# How are environment variables accessed from ".env" file if Django project deployed to AWS from Github?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-deployment, awsdeploy

I have a Django project deployed on AWS EBS from a Github repo. My secret key is kept on a .env file. I've included  the following:

settings.py

```
from decouple import config
"SECRET_KEY" = config("MY_SECRET_KEY")
```

requirements.txt

```
python-decouple==3.7
```

.env

```
MY_SECRET_KEY = "THISISMYSECRETKEY-THISISMYSECRETKEY-THISISMYSECRETKEY"
```

Since I've include .env inside my .gitignore file, the .env is not being pushed to Github. When I try to deploy my project I keep getting an error:

```
"web: decouple.UndefinedValueError: SECRET_KEY not found".
```

The project runs fine on a local server.

Comment: You can look into the [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) or if you're using Elastic Beanstalk then it provides adding ENV variables on the machine under config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ashwini's help I was able to figure it out. You can store environment variables in AWS by using the cli:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-pass-variables/

Additionally, you can view and add environment variables through the AWS dashboard: Elastic Beanstalk / Click on your environment hyperlink / Click "Configuration" (on the left side of the page) / Click the "Edit" button under the software section.